# 2 different form of confidence interval for variance estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

For iid data {$X_n$} with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, finite 4th order moment $\mu_4 = E(X_1-\mu)^4$. Let the estimator of $\sigma^2$ be $\sigma_n^2 =n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t^2-(\bar X_n)^2,$
where $\bar X_n=n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t$. By CLT we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(\sigma_n^2-\sigma^2) &\stackrel{D}{\to}N(0,\mu_4-\sigma^4) \\\\
\sqrt{n}(\sigma_n^2/\sigma^2-1) &\stackrel{D}{\to}N(0,\frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}-1).
\end{align}

let $\hat \mu_4$ be the sample version of $\mu_4$. Then from the 1st convergence result, we have that a 95% CI of $\sigma^2$ is $\sigma_n^2(1\pm1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat\mu_4/\sigma_n^4-1}{n}})$. From the 2nd convergence result, we have that a 95% CI of $\sigma^2$ is $\sigma_n^2(1\pm1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat\mu_4/\sigma_n^4-1}{n}})^{-1}$.

I think the second CI is the one commenly used. I'm wondering why the 1st CI isn't used?

Comment: How did you apply CLT here? You would have to use the multivariate delta method to obtain the asymptotic distribution of the sample variance (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377272/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-via-multivariate-delta-method) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)).

Comment: What you obtained would be the asymptotic distribution if your estimator was defined as ${1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2$ (not a good estimator, since we don't know $\mu$).

Comment: Where have you seen the second result?

Comment: the secod CI appeared in Page 53 of: A course in large sample theory by Thomas S. Ferguson